# Сложный sql запрос

Tags: oracle, group-by, sql

Есть запрос:

```
select name_fak "Факультет", 
       god "Учебный год", 
       kurs "Курс", 
       count(distinct fio) "Всего",
       (select count(distinct fio) from bi_balls_m where seex='ж') "Из них женщин",
       (select count(distinct fio) from bi_balls_m where id_fin = 1) "Бюджет",
       (select count(distinct fio) from bi_balls_m where id_fin = 1 and seex='ж') "Из них женщин"
from   bi_balls_m, fak
where  fak.id_fak = bi_balls_m.id_fak
group  by name_fak, god, kurs
order  by name_fak, god, kurs
```

Собственно, очевидно, что работать, как требуется, он не будет, подзапросы в поле select ничего не знают о группировке и считают значения по всей таблице. Каким образом это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо подзапросов вставьте:

```
sum(case when b.seex ='ж' then 1 else 0 end) "Из них женщин",
sum(case when b.id_fin=1 then 1 else 0 end) "Бюджет",
sum(case when b.id_fin=1 and b.seex ='ж' then 1 else 0 end) "Из них женщин"
```

ЗЫ И псевдоним для `bi_balls_m` добавьте, например, как выше: `b`.
ЗЗЫ Одинаковые псевдонимы (`"Из них женщин"`) не есть гуд.
ЗЗЗЫ Используйте ansi join и старайтесь не злоупотреблять `distinct`.

Comment: Почти идеально, даже не задумывался, что можно так поступать.
Но distinct злоупотребляю как раз потому, что в таблице люди могут повторяться. Например, для вашего варианта запроса выдает 164 в графе "Всего" и 822 в графе "Из них женщин". Сейчас подумаю, можно ли это как-то учесть.

Comment: @nulpatrol, приведите пример данных (на sqlfiddle.com), по описанию сложно понять, где что может множиться... видимо, есть еще какой-то разрез, который все портит.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не совсем разобрался с sqlfiddle.com.
Все просто, таблица bi_balls_m хранит балы студентов по каждому предмету. То есть один fio может повторяться сколько угодно раз, просто id предмета разный. Distinct fio как раз давал уникальные fio.

Comment: @nulpatrol, понятно. Ну тут тогда напрашивается декомпозиция таблицы. Как минимум на студентов и их оценки...  
В принципе можно и с такой таблицей работать. Сделать вложенный запрос, свернуть по каждому студенту, потом уже во внешнем запросе считать количества.

Comment: Понятное дело, с НФ тут все плохо... Но это входные данные с которыми нужно работать в таком вот неудобном виде.

Но за подсказку с использованием case внутри sum - отдельное спасибо, пусть и не здесь, но когда-то очень пригодится.

Comment: Советую посмотреть в сторону аналитических функций, помоему это то что вам нужно